# pil composite multiple images giving error

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

How can I compose all these images together? Keep in mind that I don't know the name of the images to compose, the file are chosen and added to a list by some previous code.

```
list=['file1.png', 'file2.png', 'file3.png', 'file4.png']
final = Image.alpha_composite(list[0], list[1], list[2], list[3])
final.save(f'{random.randint(1,10000)}.png')
```

Comment: Do you mean `list[0], list[1], ...`. Square brackets instead of parentheses.

Comment: In which case, you could possibly use `Image.alpha_composite(*list)`.

Comment: Tip: don't use built-in names like `list` for variables. Name it something like `filenames`, which is also clearer to what it means.

Comment: It is useful to add the actual error (+ traceback) to your question; not just the code.

Comment: @9769953 Yes I meant list[0]. However it is still not working because  alpha_composite() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given. How can I compose these 4 images together?

Comment: Did you read the PIL documentation? `alpha_composite` expects two (PIL-like) images, not filenames.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments of method `alpha_composite` are two Image objects, not filenames.

IMO, you  cannot use this method, different order of files passed to `alpha_composite` will get different result. Maybe you can try method `blend` with a fixed alpha, like 0.5

Example Code

```py
from PIL import Image

path = 'path of your holder for image files'

im = [Image.open(path+'/'+file)
    for file in ('10.png', '24.png', '38.png', '52.png')]

im1 = Image.blend(im[0], im[1], 0.5)
im2 = Image.blend(im[2], im[3], 0.5)
image1 = Image.blend(im1, im2, 0.5)
image1.show()

im3 = Image.blend(im[0], im[3], 0.5)
im4 = Image.blend(im[1], im[2], 0.5)
image2 = Image.blend(im3, im4, 0.5)
image2.show()
```

[image]